# How to pre-pend argument to filename in Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, casperjs

I'm new to firing scripts using C#.  I have a a javascript and I need to prepend casperjs so the script knows how to be executed :

```
var myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\projects\\tester\\tester\\scripts\\test.js";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "casperjs";
myProcess.Start();
```

So the above will not work, because normally to run the script via the command line you have to type;

```
>>>casperjs test.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

So the question is how to pre-pend casperjs as an argument before actually executing the script?

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Comment: Isn't `FileName` the executable and `Arguments` where you place the arguments? The script path is an argument to the casperjs executable.

Comment: you're right that is the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume casperjs runs the script - so then in the FileName you should put the path to casperjs and then first argument should be the script(what you have now in FileName).

```
        var myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\full\\path\\to\\casperjs.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\projects\\tester\\tester\\scripts\\test.js arg1 arg2";
        myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: That is a perfect solution, thank you! I'll accept it in 3 more minutes.